# Loopback - Email as a composite key

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, loopbackjs

The Scenario is,

When deleting a user, we are just updating a field called status to -1.

But while adding a user with that deleted email id, the built in user model of loopback throws error as email already exists since it checks only whether the email exists or not. I want to check whether an email exists with status 1(active user). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

your scenario sounds like a [soft delete](https://github.com/studio-mv/loopback-softdelete-mixin) mechanism. In my experience when the user is deleted in this way the best is recover the same user (status to 1 or null in soft delete) avoiding creating another.

But if you want to create another user with the same email you need customize create method in User model. Check [customization model](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Customizing-models.html)

Hope this help you!

Comment: Actually I am keeping the user's data for future reference, But If I am recovering the same user, I will loose the old data rt?

Comment: You will not, is the same user and this process only affects one column (soft_delete or active)